# How do you verify if a request is from a genuine user or from a malicious user?

Tags: http, nginx

Consider clientA which wants to verify payments and serverB which verifies payments.

ClientA sends around a million requests to serverB's API in 1 day.

However, only 1% of the requests from clientA succeed and give a 200 response. The rest end up with a 400 response.

I looked at the API documentation and the way requests are generated is correct.

But I am still undecided. How can I prove solidly that the request is malicious in this case?

Comment: To determine the difference from a true positive from a false positive, you need to understand the system and the normal and expected behavior of your users. We can't help you analyse this report, and the concepts are going to be to high-level for us to walk you through in any way that's going to be applicable to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish a *genuine* user is often simple: is the request one that the client app (be that mobile, web, embedded device, whatever) would realistically make? For example, if the request wouldn't pass client-side validation, then you can be pretty sure that it was modified or custom-made by the user, rather than using the usual client. That's not clear evidence of *malice* but it certainly indicates an abnormal user. If the request is technically valid and well-formatted but contains implausible content - for example, actual PHP code instead of a human name in a field where it's asking for somebody's name, or HTML/JS/PHP/SQL/shell/etc. metacharacters that aren't expected in that context - then that's also a pretty clear sign that something is up.

It's still not necessarily malicious, unless you can determine that it was in fact an attempt at code injection *and* that the injected code would have done something harmful. Quite plausibly, it's just somebody looking for vulnerabilities they can report for a bounty, or testing a service's security before buying it, or something like that; possibly self-interested but not in any way that's harmful to you.

But a lot of the time it's not even that. WAFs and similar products have terrible detection accuracy, usually having lots of both false positives and false negatives. They might flag something totally innocent, like somebody using angle brackets to express the normal "less than"/"greater than" concepts rather than because they're HTML metacharacters, or using backticks because they're used to Markdown making text within them stand out and not because they cause code execution in shells.

In any case, the main information you need here is just:

1. the actual request, as much of it as was logged
2. some idea what typical requests for this endpoint look like, for comparison's sake and to see whether the flagged request is actually unreasonable
3. basic knowledge about the server and application in question, both to help determine if the request is reasonable and - if not - whether it could have been harmful.

Beyond that, you want at least a little bit of security knowledge - do you know what a PHP injection is, and what it looks like? - and ideally some programming knowledge (to tell what an injection or other payload would actually do). Those, combined with some common sense about things like "this request looks totally normal except for a stray character that could have been a typo" or "this request came from e.g. Russia, where we don't do any business, and isn't associated with any user, maybe that's sketchy?" or "actually there's a lot of weird requests from that IP address even though most of them didn't flag the scanner" - are generally good enough. They won't conclusively address the question of malice - even some of the most effective malware in history was plausibly not released with any intention of malice, and none of us are mind-readers - but they'll usually suffice to differentiate "is this a normal user or not", and sometimes even "is this somebody looking for security vulnerabilities or not".